# Dictionary did not update according to full dictionary but the final element only

Tags: python, dictionary

I try to build a class that get the total number of folders, total number of files and then each sentence inside the text file.

Example of text file:

Text1.txt:

I have many things
I am a man
King of jungle

Text2.txt:

The jungle of man
No jungle no life
Your life is useless

My totals return from another class is:

totals:

```
[[["I have many things", "I am a man", "King of Jungle"]], [["The jungle of man", "No jungle no life", "Your life is useless"]]]

class Get(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_folder(self, totals=None):
        """
        Return the dictionary for sentence based on the index of folder and files
        """
        if totals is None:
            totals = self.get_files() #This is based on my another class on another file.py
        self.record = {i:{ii:totals[i][ii][iii]} for i in range(len(totals)) for ii in range(len(totals[i])) for iii in range(len(totals[i][ii]))}
        print(self.record)
```

My current output when print(self.record) is:

```
{0: {0: 'King of jungle'}, 1: {0: 'Your life is useless'}}
```

Expected output:

```
{0: {0: 'I have many things', 0: 'I am a man', 0: 'King of jungle'}, 1: {0: 'The jungle of man', 0: 'No jungle no life', 0: 'Your life is useless'}}
```

Comment: I made an update. It was wrongly input just now.

Comment: Are you sure the issue is not in ``self.get_files``?

Comment: do you want counts or indices? It is not clear what your expected output is.

Comment: The dictionary is something like this {document_index{file_index:sentence}}. Example we have a folder named "All" then within this folder we have 2 files named "File1" and "File2". Lastly, within the files, we have sentences. Ok, the sentence for each file is like this. I am a king\n I am xxx \n ............ t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that your expected output is a correct python dictionary. Can you please check it ? Also, you have a list of a list of lists of strings. Is it what you want ?

As an example of nested dictionaries, please consider the snippet below.

```
values = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
dict = {}
for i, j in enumerate(values):
    dict[i] = {}
    for k, l in enumerate(j):
        dict[i][k] = l
print(dict)
# {0: {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}, 1: {0: 'd', 1: 'e', 2: 'f'}}
```

Alternative solution

```
from collections import defaultdict
values = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
dict = {}
for i, j in enumerate(values):
    dict[str(i)] = defaultdict(list)
    for k in j:
        dict[str(i)][0].append(k)
print(dict)
# {'0': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: ['a', 'b', 'c']}),
#  '1': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: ['d', 'e', 'f']})}
```

As a dictionary comprehension

```
print({i: {k: l for k, l in enumerate(j)} for i, j in enumerate(values)})
# {0: {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}, 1: {0: 'd', 1: 'e', 2: 'f'}}
```

This last solution is fastest.

Comment: Is there no possible way to use my method to loop each sentence and make a dictionary of it

Comment: Please update your expected output. When I paste it in a print() call, it raises a SyntaxError.

Comment: I am sorry for the mistakes, I have updated my expected output.

Comment: Thank you for that. The problem now is that your inner dictionaries have the same key for multiple values, so that if you print() your expected output, only the last value corresponding to the key will be kept ({0: {0: 'King of jungle'}, 1: {0: 'Your life is useless'}}). I see two solutions here. You can use a different key for each value, or you can store a list of strings for each key.

Comment: Actually, your solution is what I needed but I would like to know whether is it possible to do it in list comprehension form instead of looping it like this way?

Comment: Is there a good way to do it by considering the performance speed also? I am trying to learn more codes in reducing the processing time if possible. Thank you so much

Comment: The dictionary comprehension is fastest yes.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. Can I ask another favour if allowed. Is it possible to write it into json file to be like: {"Sentence":[{"l":"a", "l": "b", "l": "c"}, {"l":"d", "l":"e", "l":"f"}]}?

Comment: I have never dealt with json files, sorry.

Comment: No worries. thank you so much. I have checked it as answer. thanks!